# End of days in the Talmud

Tags: talmud-gemara, messiah

Are only frightening predictions for the End of Days in the Talmud? (Like that sages wouldn't live in these time periods.) Are there also encouraging statements for these times in addition to the warnings about the many calamities will happen?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Mezeg and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: "_Are only frightening predictions for the End of Days in the Talmud?_" Could you bring citations/quotes of such frightening predictions for the End of Days in the Talmud (in the question)? "_(Like that sages wouldn't live in these time periods.)_" Who says that? where?

Comment: @TamirEvan These descriptions can be found mainly in Sanchedrin 97a-98b. The opinion of the sages eg. in 98b:3 "Ulla says: Let the Messiah come, but after my death, so that I will not see him, as I fear the suffering that will precede his coming. Likewise, Rabba says: Let the Messiah come, but after my death, so that I will not see him..." The suggestion of the predictions that it will be difficult to maintain somebody's integrity.

Answer (score 1):

The Talmud tells us about this:

> The world is [set] to exist for 6,000 years. In the first 2,000 there was desolation [that is, no Torah]. [In the next] 2,000 years the Torah flourished; and the next 2,000 years is the Messianic era.  However, because of our many sins [the Messiah is delayed and many of] these years have been lost. [Sanh. 97 a-b]

We are in the year 5784.  So the Messiah should arrive sometime in the next 216 years, and his era should last until the Jewish year 6000, which is the secular year 2239, when the material world will end.  Perhaps that is the time the prophet Isaiah refers to when he quotes God as saying:

> For, behold, I create new heavens and a new earth; and the former shall not be remembered, nor come to mind. [Is. 65:17]

The Messianic period will blend in with the World to Come, *olam haba*, when the dead will come back to life and enjoy a time that is “all Shabbat” -- *yom shekulo Shabbat*.  Unfortunately, this period will come after a horrendous world war led by King Gog from the Land of Magog, during which Good will obliterate Evil. [Ezekiel 38-39; Zechariah 21:2, 14:23; Sukkah 52, Sanhedrin 97, Sotah 49]  The only unknown in Jewish tradition at this point is when all this will happen.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all